# Python packages are not installing in my virtual environment

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, terminal, azure-functions

I set up a Python virtual environment in 'Visual Studio Code'. Here is the full path to my python interpreter:

"C:\Users\Hamid\Desktop\VisualStudio.venv\Scripts\python.exe"

I am creating an Azure function. I have the following files in my folder:

[image]

In my requirements.txt file I have the names of the Python packages I need installed for my main Python script. When I run the following command in the terminal:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get the following message:

`Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in c:\users\hamid\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.12.0)`

The Terminal doesn't seem to be connected to my Virtual Python environment. How can I set the terminal up so that it connects to the virtual enviornment?.

I came across two suggestions on stackoverflow. I tried to manually set the python interpreter and I also pressed ctrl+shift+' to reset the terminal. Unfortunately both methods did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workarounds is to activate the virtual environment and change the function run path to virtual environment folder in the VS Code terminal**:

```py
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

OR

```py
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

OR
when you open the project in VS Code, you'll get the dialog box like below and click on `yes`:

[image]

and freeze the requirements file using the cmdlet

```py
pip freeze > requirements.txt`
```

Refer to few of my workarounds SO [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73472593/16630138) and [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73871830/16630138) in regards of Virtual Environment activating in Azure Functions